# Google calendar api event movement from primary calendar to another calendar in same account

Tags: events, move, google-calendar-api

I am getting following while trying to move event from one calendar to another calendar.
the Error:-
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Cannot change the organizer of an instance. 400]Errors [Message[Cannot change the organizer of an instance.] Location[ - ] Reason[cannotChangeOrganizerOfInstance] Domain[calendar]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of event moving we can do event import it is working when compare to event.move method its worked for me we need to change the Attendees email id from out email id in to new calendar id then only we can import event from primary calendar to secondary calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't work with a Recurring event.

Regards

Comment: no it is not based on event type. commonly is not working. it is not allowing to move from primary calendar to secondary calendar